# Telethon Won't Disconnect Client

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have a problem with Telethon. I have a NewMessage() event listener, and it works just fine. But when exit the script with CTRL + C and start it again, it does not connect to the chat again.
I have to manually delete the connection in the Telegram app.

My question is:
**How can I force the client to disconnect, when I press CTRL + C or when the program is closed.**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import globals, asyncio

client = TelegramClient('anon', 
globals.api_id, globals.api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=globals.tLink))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.raw_text)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to repeatedly restart the script, it might be reasonable to not create a separate/new session for every run. Try using None to not create a .session file, instead of creating an anon.session.

```
client = TelegramClient(None, globals.api_id, globals.api_hash)
```

Comment: Hey :) 

Thx a lot, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```py
async def enviar():
   (code)

async def main():
    global ME
    ME = await info_me();
    
    enviar_var = asyncio.create_task(enviar());

    await enviar_var;
    
        
with client:
    try:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main());

    except:
        print("Encerrando...");
        future = asyncio.Future();
        future.set_result("1");
        con.close();#I am using a SQLite database, you can ignore this line
        print("Adeus!");
```